# Web UI for TCP/IP SocketServer

Tags: java, sockets, tomcat, web, server

So I've finished developing a Low-Level TCP Server in Java using Managed Threads and Server Sockets. It runs as a standard .jar and listens and handles incoming connections it receives on a ServerSocket and sends anything it receives on to another server through a Socket.

Now I'm trying to add a Web-Based UI that will handle basic things like change the external server's address, start/stop the server, know when it's running and what's connected etc.

I wanted to avoid setting up an entire Tomcat Application completely seperate from the Java Server, as they would need to share a database. So I've been looking into converting everything to Jetty, but it doesn't seem like that's the best option.

Are there better options for HTML libraries that would be good for controlling the Java Application? Or is it a better idea to move my SocketServer to a full Web-App served by Tomcat or something? If the latter, is there a way to start the SocketServer when the Web-Application starts and make sure it stays running? Or is it better to just use an embedded HTTP server in my already completed Java Application? If that then is it possible to show dynamic data or change fields within the SocketServer

EDIT:

I've still had no luck getting this design to work, but to clarify my current design and my needs.

Currently I have a Console Application where Main.java reads data from a Configuration file and creates a MyServer.java object. This Server creates a SocketServer design involving managed threads.

A Listener Thread is created that opens a SocketServer and any incoming connections spawn a worker thread that continuously reads data. All connections remain open until the connection fails to read. It does this by taking the Socket received from sSocket.accept() and stores stores it in a HashMap by calling back to MyServer.java.

In addition to this it creates another socket to another server using a regular Socket and reads data the same way. All messages received from any of the Sockets are put into a Queue.

Whenever there is something in the Queue another thread in Server.java writes each element in the queue to all open sockets.

```
public class MyServer {
    private ConcurrentHashMap<String, ISpeaker> mEndpointMap;
    private Queue<String> mOutputQueue;
    private ICallback mCallback = new ICallback() {
        public void putEndpoint(URI uri, ISpeaker speaker);
        public void removeEndpoint(URI uri);
        public void pushMessage(String message);
    }

    private Thread mClientThread;
    private Thread mListeningThread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                ServerSocket sSocket = new ServerSocket(getPort());
                Socket socket = sSocket.accept();
                socket.setSoTimeout(0);
                TcpWorkerThread workerThread = new TcpWorkerThread(socket);
                workerThread.start();
            }
        }

        class TcpWorkerThread extends Thread {
            private Socket mSocket;
            public void run() {
                try(InputStreamReader sr = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())) {
                    String content = "";
                    int read;
                    mServerCallback.putEndpoint(getUri(), new TcpStreaming(socket.getOutputStream());
                    while((read = sr.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != 1) {
                         //READ & DO STUFF
                    }
                    mServerCallback.removeEndpoint(getUri()); //read has failed, remove from output map
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private Thread mSpeakerThread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                if(mOutputQueue.size() > 0) {
                    for(ISpeaker speaker : mEndpointMap.values()) {
                        speaker.write(mOutputQueue.poll()));
                    }
            }
        }
    };

    public void StartServer() {
        mListeningThread.start();
        mClientThread.start();
        mSpaeakerThread.start();
}
```

Interface implementation

```
public class TcpStreaming implements ISpeaker {
    private final OutputStreamWriter os;
    private final URI uri;

    public TcpStreaming(URi endpoint, OutputStreamWriter os) {
        this.uri = endpoint;
        this.os = os;
    }

    public void write(String message) {
        os.write(message);
        os.flush();
    }
}
```

I want to add new functionality like seeing what Endpoints are connected, or the ability to change the address of the Client connection, or start/stop processing with a boolean and the requirements are to add this as a web interface.

So is this something that can be done simply, like by either adding an embedded Web Server that can serve HTML/JSP or possibly migrating this codebase to a Tomcat Container.
Or is this not even possible with this design? Can it be refactored to be only a Web Service? If so can I keep connections alive and processing the same way it is now?

EDIT:

So my current idea which I have mostly working is to run a RESTful Http Server using apache.http.HttpServer with HttpRequestHandlers.

I'm pulling data from the SocketServer portion of the application using a Callback Interface. Writing HTML pages and sotring them in the compilation location and loading them into a string in the HttpRequestHandler.

```
public class MainPageHandler implements HttpRequestHandler {
    private static final String fServerKey = "{$ServerAddress}";
    private static final String fConnectionTableKey = "{$ConnectionTable}";
    private final IServerCallback mCallback;

    public MainPageHandler(IServerCallback callback) {
        this.mCallback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpRequest httpRequest, HttpResponse httpResponse, HttpContext httpContext) throws HttpException, IOException {
        File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/Router/src/rest/handler/view/index.html");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        byte[] data = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        fis.read(data);
        fis.close();
        String page = new String(data);

        httpResponse.setEntity(new StringEntity(page, ContentType.TEXT_HTML));

    }
}
```

I use tags in the HTML to replace it with data after loading the string to get dynamic/live data. Functionality such as turning the server on/off is achieved using HttpHandlers as well that redirect to a page that displays something.

It's currently working, but honestly, this seems ridiculous even to me. I was hoping there would be a better solution to this. Let me know if anyone has any ideas.

Comment: I wrote a class "ServerSocketEx" years ago which handles a lot of the plumbing for doing ServerSockets. If you are interested, it's located here on SourceForge: https://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/io/ServerSocketEx.java

Comment: I appreciate it, I'll take a look to see if any improvements can be made to my own codebase. But I actually have the ServerSocket code done, and I'm adding an HTML layer on top of it (or potentially migrating it to a Web app)